# ReactJS - Image not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

I want to load a local image in ReactJS which I have put inside the "images" folder which is inside "src" folder. I am trying to display image like this :

```
<img src={require('../images/colgate.jpg')} className="card-img-top" alt="product image" />
```

But it is not displaying and shows something like this when I inspect it :

```
<img src="[object Module]" className="card-img-top" alt="product image" />
```

When I import the image using the import command like this :

```
import pic from '../images/colgate.jpg';

<img src={pic} className="card-img-top" alt="product image" />
```

The image displays by the import method but I want to display it using the src.

Comment: <img src={"'../images/colgate.jpg'"} className="card-img-top" alt="product image" />

Comment: in object module data is located in module.default

Comment: By using this --> src={"'../images/colgate.jpg'"}  , Image is still not displaying.

Comment: test src={require('../images/colgate.jpg').default}

Comment: Yes, src={require('../images/colgate.jpg').default} ---> this worked

Comment: What are you using to serve your website,. Node express, PHP, etc as placing static assets into folder and referencing then it's usually better for caching and build times / sizes.  When you require an asset in say webpack its not very efficient either, as it has to encode in something like base64, but when serving the files it can use binary.

Comment: It is in development phase.